# 3 dependent multi dropdown list same select name how to insert into mysql using php?

Tags: php, arrays

3 dependent multi dropdown list same select name at the end of the select field each drop down. When i click portfolio level option based on the div display show one dependent dropdown list among three. When i click at showed dropdown list only posted to last selected value. In that i make every drop down list last select name same; i.e `name=worklocation`.

The html code below:

```
<form method="post" action="user-work.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="pfLevel" id="portfolio_levels" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select Portfolio Level</option>
                    </select>
                </div>  

                <div style='display:none;'  id='Countryshow'  class="form-group">
                    <select name="workLocation[]" id="counrey7" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select Country</option>    
                    </select>
                </div>  

                <div style='display:none;'  id='stateshow'>
                <div  class="form-group">                     
                    <select name="" id="country6" class="form-control">                                 
                        <option value="">Select country</option>                            
                    </select>                   
                </div>
                <div  class="form-group">
                    <select name="workLocation[]" id="state6" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select State</option>
                    </select>                   
                </div>                                      
                </div>  


                <div style='display:none;'  id='cityshow'>
                <div  class="form-group">                 
                    <select name="" id="country5" class="form-control">                                 
                        <option value="">Select country</option>                            
                    </select>                   
                </div>
                <div  class="form-group">
                    <select name="" id="state5" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select state</option>
                    </select>                   
                </div>
                <div  class="form-group">
                    <select name="workLocation[]" id="city5" class="form-control">
                        <option value="">Select city</option>
                    </select>                   
                </div>          

                </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12"><div class="btn-group text-left">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-secondry">Close</button>
                        </div></div>

                    </form>
```

**php code**

```
<?php

require 'inc/database.php';
if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    $pfLevel=$_POST['pfLevel'];
    $workLocation=$_POST['workLocation'];

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO userworkinfo (intWorkLocation,userPfLevel) values(?,?)";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($workLocation,$pfLevel));
    Database::disconnect();
    echo '<script>alert("working details posted successfully");</script>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use select input name with index.

```
<select name="workLocation[0]" id="counrey7" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select Country</option>    
</select>

<select name="workLocation[1]" id="state6" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select state</option>
</select> 

<select name="workLocation[2]" id="city5" class="form-control">
   <option value="">Select city</option>
</select>
```

Comment: $workLocation=$_POST['workLocation']; how to change PHP post code

Comment: $_POST['workLocation']  returned array. $_POST['workLocation'][0], $_POST['workLocation'][1], $_POST['workLocation'][2]

Comment: $workLocation=$_POST['workLocation'][0];
$workLocation=$_POST['workLocation'][1]; $workLocation=$_POST['workLocation'][2];
working only last one

Comment: no, use $workLocation as array. $workLocation = $_POST['workLocation'];
$workLocation[0], $workLocation[1], $workLocation[2]